# Need a hint for this integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity-theory

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}+1}\,dx.$$

This is an old complex analysis exam question, so I plan to use the residue theorem.

How can I first deal with the square-root, cubed term?  I've been trying to find a clever substitution to reduce the problem to a simple one but so far I have not found a good one...

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: you could always use the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$ and use partial fractions to get a couple rational functions with maximum degree of 2. Might not be the quickest solution, but it is what comes to mind

Comment: Hi @brevanellefsen - thanks for your comment, I will try this now...

Comment: $du = -1/\sqrt{x}dx = -1/u dx$ so yes you will be getting a rational function.

Comment: @mathreadler what? for the sub $u=\sqrt{x}$ you get $du = \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{dx}{2u}$

Comment: Yes you are right. But you will still be getting a rational function.

Comment: I had tried this already but quit on it too early because I was stuck with a Jacobian factor of $\sqrt{x}2$ ... but now  I see that it is simply just 2y...thanks again @brevanellefsen ... I will try to compute the integral now using residues ...

Comment: Oh the effort. Well good luck any way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**: Every time I see integrand like this which integrate over $(0,\infty)$, I will transform it to a beta integral and follows my nose.

**Spoiler 1**

> Let $\displaystyle\;y = x^{3/2}\;$ and $\displaystyle\;z = \frac{y}{1+y}\;$, we have

**Spoiler 2**

> $$\begin{align} \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}+1}&= \int_0^\infty \frac{dy^{2/3}}{y+1} = \frac23 \int_0^\infty \frac{y^{2/3-1} dy}{y+1}\\ &= \frac23 \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)^{2/3-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+y}\right)^{1/3-1}\frac{dy}{(1+y)^2}\\ &= \frac23 \int_0^1 z^{2/3-1}(1-z)^{1/3-1}dz \\ &= \frac23\frac{\Gamma(2/3)\Gamma(1/3)}{\Gamma(2/3+1/3)} = \frac23 \frac{\pi}{\sin\frac{\pi}{3}}\\ & = \frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} \end{align} $$

**Update** (sorry, this part is too hard to setup as spoiler correctly)

If you really want to compute the integral using residue, you can

1. change variable to $y = x^{3/2}$.
2. pick the branch cut of $y^{-1/3}$ in the resulting integrand along the positive real axis.
3. set up a integral over the contour:
   $$C :=  +\infty - \epsilon i\quad\to\quad -\epsilon-\epsilon i\quad \to \quad -\epsilon + \epsilon i \quad\to\quad +\infty + \epsilon i$$

If you fix the argument of $y^{-1/3}$ to be zero on the upper branch of $C$, you will have

$$\left(1 - e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)\int_0^\infty \frac{y^{-1/3}dy}{y+1} = \int_C \frac{y^{-1/3}dy}{y+1} =^{\color{blue}{[1]}} 2\pi i\mathop{\text{Res}}_{y = -1}\left(\frac{y^{-1/3}}{y+1}\right) = 2\pi i e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}}$$

This will give you
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}+1} = \frac23 \int_0^\infty \frac{y^{-1/3} dy}{y+1} = \frac{4\pi i}{3}\left(\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}}}{1 - e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{3}}}\right) = \frac{2\pi}{3\sin\frac{\pi}{3}} = \frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ Since the integrand $\frac{y^{-1/3}}{y+1}$ goes to $0$ faster than $\frac{1}{|y|}$ as $|y| \to \infty$, we can complete the contour $C$ by a circle of infinite radius and evaluate the integral over $C$ by taking residue at poles within the extended contour.

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: Hi @achillehui, I am pretty inexperienced with Beta functions so for now I will try to grind out the residue computations.  Can I ask you a silly, possibly trivial question?

Comment: I am using a wedge to enclose one pole -- the upper semicircle was a bad idea, as there is a pole at -1.  So the integral over the edge that is the positive axis is the desired integral.  The integral over the arc goes to zero, easily shown.  However I am having some trouble estimating the integral over the third edge - the imaginary axis.  After the ML - bound, I get $\frac{\pi R y}{|y|^3-1}$.  Does this term go to zero as R grows to infinity?  My trouble is that |y| is not R...I am not on a circular arc but rather I am on a straight line ... Thanks, @achillehui

Comment: @User001 I have added an residue based approach.

Comment: Hi @achillehui, I don't understand your contour -- is it sort of like a dog-bone contour?  Also, is there anything wrong with my choosing a simple wedge contour that is essentially a quarter-circle in the first quadrant, with a semicircular indent around the origin to avoid the branch point, and cutting away the negative axis?  The estimate over the circular indent is easy to give and the integral is zero on it, as the radius shrinks to zero.  Is this ok?  Thanks,

Comment: same method and same contour as in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#Par_une_int.C3.A9grale_de_contour to prove that $$\zeta(s) = e^{- i \pi s} \frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2 i \pi} \oint_C \frac{y^{s-1}}{e^y-1}dy$$
this is because of the $y^a$ with non integer $a$ in the integrand.

Comment: @User001 Mine is equivalent to a keyhole contour. I don't want to describe the circle around origin as it wastes too many keystrokes for nothing. For your contour, I don't think evaluate it along the imaginary axis is easier than your original integral.

Comment: Hi @achillehui, I redid the problem using a keyhole contour, cutting away the positive axis.  Unfortunately, now the integrals over the two lines above and below the positive axis ... are canceling each other out (while the integrals over the large and small circles are zero, as desired)...what do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001 what form of integrand you are using? if you uses the one I use, it won't cancel out. There is a factor $e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ coming from the $y^{-1/3}$.

Comment: I am using $\frac{2z}{z^3+1}$, primarily because I want to be able to solve it myself to train for exam day... hmm...so my integrand is a bad choice, huh? @achillehui, thanks ...

Comment: I will try your approach now, thanks @achillehui...

Comment: @User001, if you want to use your integrand, you should use a contour like $[0,R] \cup \{ R e^{i\theta} : \theta \in [0,\frac{2\pi}{3}] \} \cup \{ r e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}} : r \in [0,R] \}$.

Comment: Ooh righttt, the estimates are easy to give on this wedge rather than having trouble on the imaginary axis, I will try now -- must also include a small circular indent to avoid the origin, where there is a branch point ... thanks @achillehui ...

Comment: Sorry, can I ask you one last question?  So, all the odd powers and fractional powers of z need branch cuts, but even powers do not - is my thinking correct?  So... $z^3$ requires a branch cut.  What do you think? Thanks @achillehui ...

Comment: @User001 you need a branch cut when and only when the power is not an integer. there is no branch cut for $z^3$.

Comment: Ok got it.  My answer agrees with yours - the computations at the end were tedious, as usual, but I survived.  Ok so no need for the circular indent around the origin then, since that is not a branch point.  Thanks so much for your patience and for answering all of my questions.  I learned so much from you tonight :-) Have a great night @achillehui :-)

Answer (score 11):

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^{3/2} + 1}$$
$$=2\int\frac{u}{u^3 + 1}du$$
Depending on how you want to solve the problem, you could start working from here  using residue theory or save some work and break down into partial fractions
$$= \frac{2}{3} \int \frac{u}{u^2 - u + 1}du + \frac{2}{3} \int \frac{1}{u^2 - u + 1}du - \frac{2}{3}\int \frac{1}{u+1}du$$
The first should fall to a $u$-sub, the second by completing the square (giving an answer in terms of $\arctan$) and the last is trivial. Of course, if you *have* to use residue theory than this is somewhat redundant :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $t=\sqrt x$. Then $dt=\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx$, so $dx=2\sqrt x\ dt=2t\ dt$.

We have

$$\int\frac{2t}{t^3+1}dt$$

This integral is not going to get very simple as you can see via wolfram. However we can integrate by parts and use arctan.

$u=\frac{1}{t^3+1}$ and $dv=2t\ dt$

So $du=\frac{-3t^2}{(t^3+1)^2}dt$ and $v=t^2$

We have

$$\frac{t^2}{t^3+1}+\int \frac{3t^4}{(t^3+1)^2}$$

Now at least the term outside the integral is $0$, so we can focus on the integral. You should be able to use partial fractions at this point, and like I said there will be an arctan. I've checked this far with wolfram, by the way, but I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Hmm... it almost seems easier to just use partial fractions than to use residue theory here. I took the same approach, more or less.

Comment: Im sure you're right. Like I said, judging from Wolfram's indefinite integral, its not going to get any easier than partial fractions.

Comment: Hi @brevanellefsen, the integrand becomes an even function (odd / odd) and we can extend the integral over the whole real line, divide by two, and integrate, over an upper semi circular contour, which should enclose two poles.  I think ... not 100% sure, but will try now :-)